# ComboBox menu repeat bug after typing in textbox in Winform app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, combobox, textbox

I have a primitive app with 2 comboBoxes. They work fine after first starting the app.

[image: Screenshot1]

However after typing in text in the search bar and pressing enter, the comboboxes loop their contents.

[image: Screenshot2]

It happens after I type in the textbox, even if I do not press enter. Every time I press a key another repeat list of options appends to the comboBox.
How do I prevent this comboBox malfunction?  Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Nick Knapp
//CSCI 363 Fall 2019
namespace c363_hw3_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Text = "Library Literature Search";
            this.BackColor = Color.White;

            comboBox2.Items.Add("All");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Books");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Papers");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Films");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("CDs");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Other");
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;


            comboBox1.Items.Add("Title");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Author");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Publisher");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("ISBN");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            // this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEnter);
            //this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
            this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
            textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed);

        }
        private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: The code you posted does not show where items where added to the ComboBox on KeyPress.

Comment: I moved all of the comboBox add statements into the public Form1() function and now everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct but have you ever tried these 2 method after calling combo boxes?

````
comboBox1.ResetText();
comboBox1.Items.Clear();```

i think it works
````

Answer (score 0):

```
private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```